# How to use HTML tags in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am trying to include HTML tags in groovy code, My requirement is to add something like -- thanks and regards (in one line), in next line a image, followed by name (in new line), kindly let me know how I can achieve this.

I have tried below and it didn't worked.

```
​body: """
Approval is required. Please provide acceptance \n
Visit the below link to approval/decline \n\n
Note This is system generated email
""" + ''' </p><p Regards,</p>src="<image path>" alt="yes"><br><br><b><span
 Cloud></b></span><br>myname<br></p>'''​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​, mimeType: 'text/html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the Groovy MarkupBuilder (https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html)?

I would solve your question like:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def markup = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)

markup.html {
    head {
        title('Approval')
    }
    body {
        mkp.yieldUnescaped('Approval is required. Please provide acceptance<br/>Visit the below link to approval/decline<br/><br/>Note This is system generated email')
        p ('Regards,')
        img(alt: 'your alt text', src: 'your image url')
        p ('YamunaS')
    }
}

writer.toString()
```

​
Which would result in:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Approval</title>
  </head>
  <body>Approval is required. Please provide acceptance<br/>Visit the below link to approval/decline<br/><br/>Note This is system generated email
    <p>Regards,</p>
    <img alt='your alt text' src='your image url' />
    <p>YamunaS</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then rendered:
[image]

If you want to put the first sentences/lines into a paragraph or div container as well, just follow above way. A div-container would open a new closure again. For a full example including some stylesheets you can also have a look in [one of my examples](https://github.com/besessener/BGGWallPaper/blob/2728e8f0105a6c19685c618813f33f813f897f98/src/main/groovy/me/games/collection/HtmlBuilder.groovy#L27). It generates html dynamically and uses it in context of Springboot (which is probably too much for you now)